# SQL check if date is on JUNE

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I have this query

```
SELECT SESSIONID, SESSIONDATE, CONCAT ('$', SESSIONPRICE)
FROM SESSIONS
WHERE SESSIONDATE = (%-JUN-%);
```

which does not do what i want it to do, I want it to check if session date is on the month of June. How would I do this?

A picture of session dates is below.
[image: session dates]

Comment: use `month(sessiondate)=6` if the column is of datatype `date`.

Comment: Did you create SESSIONDATE as a VARCHAR or something Stringy?

Comment: If so, make it a DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP then you can use sensible MYSQL date functions on it, search it properly and sort it properly. Dates in String data types is a bad idea, If you want to see it in a specific format, do the formatting in the presentation layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SESSIONID, SESSIONDATE, CONCAT ('$', SESSIONPRICE)
FROM SESSIONS
WHERE SESSIONDATE like '%-JUN-%';
```

Comment: thanks for all your help guys but this answer seemed to have done it

Comment: @Daniel So it is a text column data type. That should be fixed!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901741/sql-check-if-date-is-on-june/39901799?noredirect=1#comment67089054_39901741

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SESSIONID, SESSIONDATE, CONCAT ('$', SESSIONPRICE)
FROM SESSIONS
WHERE EXTRACT( MONTH FROM `SESSIONDATE ` ) = 6
```

Comment: Talk about walking round the block and sneeking up on it from behind :) :)